# Large Denormalized Table Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a single large denormalized table that mirrors the make up of a fixed length flat file that is loaded yearly.  112 columns and 400,000 records.  I have a unique clustered index on the 3 columns that make up the where clause of the query that is run most against this table.  Index Frag is .01.  Performance on the query is good, sub second.  However, returning all the records takes almost 2 minutes.  The execution plan shows 100% of the cost is on a Clustered Index Scan (not seek).

There are no queries that require a join (due to the denorm).  The table is used for reporting.  All fields are type nvarchar (of the length of the field in the data file).

Beyond normalizing the table.  What else can I do to improve performance.

Comment: How much data is in the table (bytes)? What kind of network connection do you have? 2 minutes sounds reasonable for a large amount of data.

Comment: It's doing a scan because you're returning all records... so there's no reason to do a seek.  Like @Oded is suggesting, your performance is going to be based on your network... unless you simply find a way to return less data, that'll be your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Try paginating the query.  You can split the results into, let's say, groups of 100 rows.  That way, your users will see the results pretty quickly.  Also, if they don't need to see all the data every time they view the results, it will greatly cut down the amount of data retrieved.

Beyond this, adding parameters to the query that filter the data will reduce the amount of data returned.

This post is a good way to get started with pagination: [SQL Pagination Query with order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098535/sql-pagination-query-with-order-by)

Just replace the "50" and "100" in the answer to use page variables and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ideas.  First, if you don't need nvarchar, switch these to varchar.  That will halve the storage requirement and should make things go faster.

Second, be sure that the lengths of the fields are less than nvarchar(4000)/varchar(8000).  Anything larger causes the values to be stored on a separate page, increasing retrieval time.

Third, you don't say how you are retrieving the data.  If you are bringing it back into another tool, such as Excel, or through ODBC, there may be other performance bottlenecks.

In the end, though, you are retrieving a large amount of data, so you should expect the time to be much longer than for retrieving just a handful of rows.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for all rows, you'll always get a scan.

400,000 rows X 112 columns X 17 bytes per column is 761,600,000 bytes. (I pulled 17 out of thin air.) Taking two minutes to move 3/4 of a gig across the network isn't bad. That's roughly the throughput of my server's scheduled backup to disk.

Do you have money for a faster network?